# Connecting a PIC16F1827 to a LCD SPLC780D

Tags: c, pic, lcd, mplab

I am trying to read the values of an accelerometer on a LCD SPL780D. However, before that I am testing to read values directly from the PIC to the LCD to ensure that it is working properly. There seems to be some problems with the program, printed characters are right-shifting sometimes and the LCD doesn't print the characters requested in the code. I am using MPLAB XC8 for programming the PIC.

Here is a picture of the LCD:
[LCD when trying to print "123"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMhCz.jpg)

Here is a picture of the breadboard:
[Breadboard connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEGVi.jpg)

```
Pin(LCD)         PIC
16               gnd
15               +5V
14               RA3
13               RA2
12               RA1
11               RA0
10
.
.
6                RA4
5                GND
4                RA6
3                RES to GND
2                +5V
1                GND
```

Here is the MPLAB XC8 code:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "lcd.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#define D4 LATAbits.LATA0 //LCD Databit D4
#define D5 LATAbits.LATA1 //LCD Databit D5
#define D6 LATAbits.LATA2 //LCD Databit D6
#define D7 LATAbits.LATA3 //LCD Databit D7
#define EN LATAbits.LATA4 //LCD Enable
#define RS LATAbits.LATA6 //LCD Register Select
#define LCD_STROBE() {EN=1; __delay_us(1); EN=0;}

/*void lcd_write(unsigned char c)
{
if(c & 0x80) D7=1; else D7=0;
if(c & 0x40) D6=1; else D6=0;
if(c & 0x20) D5=1; else D5=0;
if(c & 0x10) D4=1; else D4=0;
LCD_STROBE();
if(c & 0x08) D7=1; else D7=0;
if(c & 0x04) D6=1; else D6=0;
if(c & 0x02) D5=1; else D5=0;
if(c & 0x01) D4=1; else D4=0;
LCD_STROBE();
__delay_us(50);
}*/


void Lcd_SetBit(char data_bit) //Based on the Hex value Set the Bits of the Data Lines
{
    if(data_bit& 0x01) 
        D4 = 1;
    else
        D4 = 0;

    if(data_bit& 0x02)
        D5 = 1;
    else
        D5 = 0;

    if(data_bit& 0x04)
        D6 = 1;
    else
        D6 = 0;

    if(data_bit& 0x08) 
        D7 = 1;
    else
        D7 = 0;

    __delay_us(50);
}

void Lcd_Cmd(char a)
{
    char Lower_Nibble,Upper_Nibble;
    Lower_Nibble = a&0x0F;
    Upper_Nibble = a&0xF0;

    Lcd_SetBit(Upper_Nibble>>4);       //Send upper half by shifting by 4
    RS = 0;             // => RS = 1
    LCD_STROBE();
    __delay_ms(2);
    Lcd_SetBit(Lower_Nibble); //Send Lower half
    LCD_STROBE();
    __delay_ms(5);
}


void Lcd_Clear()
{
    RS = 0;
    Lcd_Cmd(1); //Clear the LCD
    //Lcd_Cmd(2); //Move the cursor to first position
    RS = 1;
    __delay_ms(2);
}

void Lcd_Set_Cursor(char a, char b)
{
    char temp,z,y;
    if(a== 1)
    {
      temp = 0x80 + b-1; //80H is used to move the cursor
        z = temp & 0x0F; //Lower 8-bits
        y = temp & 0xF0; //Upper 8-bits
        Lcd_Cmd(z); //Set Row
        Lcd_Cmd(y); //Set Column
    }
    else if(a== 2)
    {
        temp = 0xC0 + b-1;
        z = temp & 0x0F; //Lower 8-bits
        y = temp & 0xF0; //Upper 8-bits
        Lcd_Cmd(z); //Set Row
        Lcd_Cmd(y); //Set Column
    }


}

void lcd_goto(char line, char column)
{
    unsigned char z,y;
    unsigned char data = 0x80;
    if(line == 2)
        data = 0xC0;
    data += column;

    y = data & 0xF0; //Upper 8-bits
    z = data>>4; //Lower 8-bits


    Lcd_Cmd(y); //Set Column
    Lcd_Cmd(z); //Set Row
}


void LCD_String_xy(char row,char pos,char *a)
{
    if(row==0)
        Lcd_Cmd((pos & 0x0F)| 0x80);
    else if (row==1)
        Lcd_Cmd((pos & 0x0F)|0xC0);
    Lcd_Print_String(a);
}

void Lcd_Start(void)
{   
    RS = 0;
    EN = 0;
    __delay_ms(20);
    Lcd_Cmd(0x02);
    __delay_ms(5);
    Lcd_Cmd(0x02);      //according to datasheet
    __delay_us(200);
    Lcd_Cmd(0x28);      //4-bit, 2-line, 5x8 dots
    Lcd_Cmd(0x0C);      //Display on, cursor off, blink off
    Lcd_Cmd(0x06);      //entry mode   
    Lcd_Clear();
}

void Lcd_Print_Char(char data)  //Send 8-bits through 4-bit mode
{
   char Lower_Nibble,Upper_Nibble;
   Lower_Nibble = data&0x0F;
   Upper_Nibble = data&0xF0;

   Lcd_SetBit(Upper_Nibble>>4);             //Send upper half by shifting by 4
   RS = 1;             // => RS = 1
   LCD_STROBE();
   //for(unsigned long i=2130483; i<=0; i--)  NOP(); 
   __delay_ms(1);
   Lcd_SetBit(Lower_Nibble); //Send Lower half
   RS = 1;
   LCD_STROBE();
   __delay_ms(1);
   //for(unsigned long i=2130483; i<=0; i--)  NOP();
   //__delay_ms(50);
   __delay_ms(5);
}

void Lcd_Print_String(char *a)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
       Lcd_Print_Char(a[i]);  //Split the string using pointers and call the Char function 
}
```

This is where we call the functions:

```
//Configuration Bits-------------------------------------------------------
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#pragma config FOSC=INTOSC, CLKOUTEN=ON //InternOscillator, ClockOut ON
#pragma config IESO=OFF, FCMEN=OFF //FCM/IESO OFF
#pragma config STVREN=ON, MCLRE=ON //StackOverflowReset ON,MasterClear ON
#pragma config WDTE=OFF, CP=OFF //Watchdog OFF,CodeProtection OFF
#pragma config PWRTE=ON, WRT=OFF //PowerUpTimer ON, WriteProtection OFF
#pragma config PLLEN=OFF, LVP=ON //PLL OFF, Low-Voltage Programming OFF
#pragma config CPD=OFF, BOREN=OFF, BORV=LO //DataProtection OFF,Brownout OFF
//Headerfiler----------------------------------------------------------------
#include <xc.h>
#include "lcd.h"
//Huvudprogram----------------------------------------------------------------
void init(void);
void main()
{
    Lcd_Start();
    init(); //Initiera pic

    while(1) //Oändlig huvudloop
    {
        Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);
        //lcd_goto(1,1);
        Lcd_Clear();
        Lcd_Print_String("123");
        __delay_ms(2000);
    }
}

void init(void)
{
    OSCCON = 0b01101000;        //intern klocka 4MHz
    ANSELA = 0b00000000;        //alla bitar RA0-RA7 digitala
    ANSELB = 0b00000000;        //alla bitar RB0-RB7 digitala
    TRISA = 0x00;               //alla A-bitar utgångar
    TRISB = 0x00;               //alla B-bitar utgångar
    CCP3CON = 0b00001100;       //ccp3 i pwm
    CCPTMRS = 0b01001010;       //ccp3 i timer2
    //PR2 = 254;
    T2CON = 0b00000100;         //timer 2 på, prescaler 1, ger fpwm = 4kHz
}
```

Some parts of the code is disabled due to testing(//code). With this code we get the output from the attached image. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Suggest simplifying code: `if(data_bit& 0x01) D4 = 1; else D4 = 0;` -> `D4 = !!(data_bit & 0x01);`

Comment: You are mixing `char`s and `unsigned char`s. Every bitwise operation should be done on unsigned types. I suggest you use `uint8_t` for almost everything (you need to `#include <stdint.h>`; XC8 is very bad at implementing C99, but I think it has that header).

Comment: I'm not familar with your display. I guess you had to send ASCII characters.